# How to add sorting function for numbers to .filter() function

Tags: javascript

I have a data in JSON format, I am currently working on creating data filtering.
I created a sorting of numbers from smallest to largest and reverse, and sorting of names, which work when clicking on input [checkbox]. They work well, but individually and confuse each other's result (i.e. if you click on price sorting, it knocks down sorting by product name and reverse). I want to connect them in .filter() function, but I don't understand how to do it correctly.

Sort works, but on click on other checkbox knocks previous sort values:

```
filters.addEventListener('input', filter);

function filter() {
    const category = [...filters.querySelectorAll('input[name="category"]:checked')].map(v => v.value);

    output(array.filter(v => (!category.length || category.includes(v.category.name)))
);

if(document.getElementById('price_up').checked) {
        return output(array.sort(function (a, b){
            return a.price - b.price;
    }))
}

function output(result) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.map(v => `
       <div>${ v.price }</div>
       <div>${ v.category.name }</div>
    `)
.join('');
}

output(array)
```

I want to implement something similar, but my code is not working:

```
filters.addEventListener('input', filter);

function filter() {
    const priceUp = document.getElementById('price_up').checked,
          priceDown = document.getElementById('price_down').checked,
    category = [...filters.querySelectorAll('input[name="category"]:checked')].map(v => v.value);

    output(array.filter(v => (
        (!priceUp.length || array.sort(function (a, b){
            return a.price - b.price;
        })) &&
        (!category.length || category.includes(v.category.name))
    ))
);

function output(result) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.map(v => `
     <div>${ v.price }</div>
     <div>${ v.category.name }</div>
    `)
.join('');
}

output(array)
```

I would be glad for any help.

Comment: First filter, then sort: `newArray = array.filter(...).sort(...)`

Comment: In that case you can do `filtered = array.filter(...); if (checkbox.checked) { filtered.sort(...); }`

Comment: @Barmar, It is possible in more detail, I am a beginner in JavaScript and still do not know much, but I am trying. The question is that I know chaining `.filter().sort()`, and I did it, but then it always sorts. But I need to sort it only if the desired checkbox is pressed.

Comment: @Barmar, And at the end, I will just add this filter variable to output function, did I understand correctly? `output(filtered)`

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Barmar, Thank you so much! Now I will try to implement all this.

Comment: be careful that sort changes the input array too

Comment: @quirimmo, but `.filter()` creates a copy of the array, and I apply `.sort()` after `.filter()`. Means that I am sorting a copy of the array, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Barmar helped to solve the problem, I used the chainig with conditions and all worked. Of course this can be optimized, but this is later, now I am happy with it

```
output(array
    .filter(v => (!category.length || category.includes(v.category.name)))
    .sort(function (a, b){
        if(document.getElementById('price_up').checked)
        return b.price - a.price;
    })
```

Comment: If you see none posting a better answer in 2 days (if im not wrong), you should accept your own answer with the green tick.